# Joining several tables and views

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view

```
  SELECT  dbo.Monitor_Request.WorkDesc
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Request_ID
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Due_Dt
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Attempts
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Status_Ind
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Create_Dt
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.Monitor_ID
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.ByCustomer_ID
          , dbo.Monitor_Request.ByCompanyID
          , dbo.CompanyShim.Company_Name
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.HouseName
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.Street
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.Town
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.City
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.County
          , dbo.PostalAddressShim.Postcode
    FROM  dbo.PostalAddressShim 
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.CompanyShim ON dbo.PostalAddressShim.Address_ID = dbo.CompanyShim.Company_Address_ID 
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER ON dbo.PostalAddressShim.Address_ID = dbo.CUSTOMER.Address_ID 
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Monitor_Request ON dbo.CUSTOMER.Customer_ID = dbo.Monitor_Request.ByCustomer_ID 
                                                  AND dbo.CompanyShim.Company_ID = dbo.Monitor_Request.ByCompanyID
```

I have created a view to display customer details with their addresses. A customer can be an individual or a company. They are stored in in different tables. For individuals the details are stored in a table called Customer and the company details are stored in the Company table. I am trying to create a view of all the customers in the database to display their addresses. When I join the tables separately I am getting the address details but if I am joining both the tables(Customer and Company) at once I am not getting null values for address details columns.

How can I get all the address details of the customers (Individual or company) from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely found a need to use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and every time I encounter it, it forces me to think from right to left complicating things.

If I didn't goof up to badly, following joins should be equivalent to what you have written

**SQL Statement**

```
dbo.Monitor_Request mr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customer c ON c.Customer_ID = mr.ByCustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CompanyShim cs ON cs.Company_ID = mr.ByCompanyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PostalAddressShim pas ON pas.Address_ID = c.Address_ID
                                             AND pas.Address_ID = cs.Company_Address_ID
```

Now this is something I **can** read and theorize about. What's immediate obvious from this statement is the `AND` clause in joining the adresses with customers and companies effectively negating each other and returning no adresses at all.

My guess is you should simply

- replace your `RIGHT JOINS` with `LEFT JOINS`
- use `OR` instead of `AND`

**SQL Statement**

```
dbo.Monitor_Request mr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Customer c ON c.Customer_ID = mr.ByCustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CompanyShim cs ON cs.Company_ID = mr.ByCompanyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PostalAddressShim pas ON pas.Address_ID = c.Address_ID
                                             OR pas.Address_ID = cs.Company_Address_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, try changing your `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`s to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.